# How to automatically resize JFrame if elements are too large?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have been researching for 30 minutes on how to automatically resize a `JFrame` when the elements are too large. I am trying to fit line segments inside the `JFrame` but  it always exceeds the space but does not automatically generate more space.

What should I do?

```
DrivePanel panel = new DrivePanel(aCar, coordinates); 
JFrame application = new JFrame();

application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
application.add(panel); 
application.setSize(600,600);
application.setVisible(true);
```

Example of output:
[image]

Comment: For better help sooner please post a [mcve]

Comment: How large? Add scroll? Scale to a preffered size? What do you want from us? For mor space concatenate 4 monitors

Comment: If 600×600 is too small, change the values in your `setSize(600,600)` statement. If that’s not an appropriate solution, you have to include the actual requirements in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider :

- if you are doing custom painting on your panel, remember that the panel's size it's not changed by what you are drawing.
  For example, if the "last" point (i mean the point with the biggest values of x and y) is drawn at (1000,1000) coordinates, you should set the preferred size of your panel in order to contain it.
- To let your application using the preferred size of your components, you should call application.pack() (where application is your JFrame object) instead of setting size manually.
- If your panel is too big to be displayed enterily on your screen, you might add it to a JScrollPane, and then add the scrollpane to your jframe (not the panel itself).
  The scrollpane will automatically use scroll bars if your panel can't be fully displayed on your screen.

So consider this small example, based on your code :

```
DrivePanel panel = new DrivePanel(aCar, coordinates); 
JFrame application = new JFrame();

application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000)); // change 1000,1000 with the coordinates you need ...
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
application.add(scrollPane); 
application.pack();
application.setVisible(true);
```

Hope this helps :)